# When innerHTML overwrites existing nodes, does it not recreate new event listeners for such nodes?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, innerhtml

I am using vanila JS to create a Todo list app. I'm fetching data from firebase realtime db and iterating over the array with a for loop.

```
function render(itemsArray) {
 messagesEl.innerHTML = "";

 for (let i = 0; i < itemsArray.length; i++) {
let currentID = itemsArray[i][0];
let currentMessage = itemsArray[i][1];

let newEl = `
    <li>
    <p class="message">
        ${currentMessage}
    </p>
    <button class="${currentID}" id="delete-btn">Del</button>
    </li>
`;

messagesEl.innerHTML += newEl;

let delBtn = document.querySelector(`.${currentID}`);
delBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log(currentID);
});
 }
}
```

In the loop, I'm attaching an event listener to the button. But the listener works only on the last item. I read that this is because the innerHTML overwrites the existing nodes.

**My question** is that, if it overwrites - i.e., creates new nodes, then it'll be recreating the event listeners also and they should work, is it? Kindly help me understand this.
I'm aware of the event delegation thing, just trying to understand the overwrite part. Thanks.

Comment: If you overwrite elements with listeners on them you remove the listeners. You will have to either a) attach new listeners to the new elements or b) use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) and attach a listener to a parent element that contains the updated HTML instead.

Comment: “then it'll be recreating the event listeners also” — If you `console.log` the value of `innerHTML`, do you see the event listener anywhere in the source code? No. So they won’t be recreated because the value you assign doesn’t include the code to create them.